# Apache POI XSLFSlide page number

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, openxml

Is there any way to add page number to newly created slide with style inherited from previous slide?

```
XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("templateFile.pptx"));
    final XSLFSlide[] slides = slideShow.getSlides();
    XSLFSlideMaster defaultMaster = slideShow.getSlideMasters()[0];
    XSLFSlideLayout titleLayout = defaultMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE_ONLY);
    final XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide(titleLayout);
//how to set slide number for slide?
```

**UPDATE**
Based on @Andreas Kühntopf answer I did some changes but it didn't help. Original slide uses TITLE_ONLY layout and has numbering in Powerpoint, but newly created slide doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create the new XSLFSlide using

```
slideShow.createSlide(layout);
```

where layout is the XSLFSlideLayout you can get from the master sheet
using

```
XSLFSlideMaster defaultMaster = slideShow.getSlideMasters()[0];    
XSLFSlideLayout titleLayout = defaultMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE);
```

Maybe you have to adjust where you get your layout from, but basically this
should be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! But it didn't help. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, combined with @Andreas Kuhntopf answer, I came to solution. First i need to select correct style for slide and later I need to manually copy `spPr` element of type `numSld`

```
        XSLFSlideMaster defaultMaster = slideShow.getSlideMasters()[0];
        XSLFSlideLayout titleLayout = defaultMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.TITLE_ONLY);
        newSlide = slideShow.createSlide(titleLayout);
        final List<CTShape> spList = slide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getSpTree().getSpList();
        for (CTShape ctShape : spList) {
            try {
                final STPlaceholderType.Enum type;
                type = ctShape.getNvSpPr().getNvPr().getPh().getType();
                if (type == STPlaceholderType.SLD_NUM) {
                    final CTShape newSlideNumber = newSlide.getXmlObject().getCSld().getSpTree().addNewSp();
                    newSlideNumber.set(ctShape);
                    break;

                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                //Just ignore exception, this rather bad code style is used to avoid multiple checks
            }
        }
```